# How to assign orders for Divs on mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I have a desktop view webpage similar to the picture below. What I'm trying to do is to create a mobile view which shows my boxes (divs) based on numbers that I marked in the picture.
Is there a any way to do it using bootstrap 4?
[my webpage view on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ5mt.jpg)

Comment: use order property of flexbox

Comment: As sahil mentioned, flexbox could possibly pull this off. If using javascript is an option, you may want to look at [intention.js](http://intentionjs.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this in your media query for mobile devices.

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#col2 {
    order: 1;
    background-color:#F1A615;
    padding:20px;
}

#col5 {
    order: 2;
    background-color:#EF2525;  
    padding:20px;
}

#col3 {
    order: 3;
    background-color:#F1A615;
    padding:20px;
}

#col4 {
    order: 4;
    background-color:#F1A615;
    padding:20px;
}
#col1{
     order: 5;
     background-color:#09D013;
     padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="col1">...column 1...</div>
    <div id="col2">...column 2...</div>
    <div id="col3">...column 3...</div>
    <div id="col4">...column 4...</div>
    <div id="col5">...column 5...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to show the divs on top of each other on mobile.
I don't know if you can handle this with classes provided by bootstrap 4, but you can achieve this with some absolute positioning.

https://jsfiddle.net/3sd0zuto/

In this example I start mobile first. All divs are stacked on top of each other in a semantic way.
When a certain breakpoint is reached I add `position: absolute` to div 2 and 5. This will break them away from the default order. They won't take up any space anymore so div 3 and 4 will fall in line behind div 1.